# Descartes' rule of signs says $x^4+x^3-4x^2+x+1$ should have two or zero positive real roots, but it only has one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Descartes' rule of signs not working for the equation $x^4+x^3-4x^2+x+1$.

Descartes sign rule is showing $2$ or $0$ positive real roots, but it has only $1$ positive real root.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It would help if you showed your attempt.

Comment: Count roots with multiplicity.  $1$ is a double root, note $x^4+x^3-4x^2+x+1
 = (x^2+3x+1)(x-1)^2$.

Comment: Be sure to count roots "with multiplicity".

Comment: $x^4+x^3-4x^2+x+1$ has $1$ as a double root

Comment: And the other two roots are $x = \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$, which are real but negative.